# Django-Rest-Framework-Use of foreign key in a reverse relation

Tags: python, django, serialization, django-rest-framework, foreign-keys

**models.py**

```
class ProductsDescription(models.Model):
    category = models.CharField(max_length=255)
    name = models.CharField(max_length=255)
    price = models.DecimalField(max_digits=255,decimal_places=2)
    description = models.TextField()
    specification = models.TextField()
    photos = models.URLField()

class Cart(models.Model):
    UserId = models.PositiveIntegerField()
    ProductId = models.PositiveIntegerField()
    Quantity = models .PositiveIntegerField()
    Date = models.DateTimeField(auto_now= True)

    key = models.ForeignKey(ProductsDescription,related_name='connection')
```

**views.py**

```
class CartApi(APIView):
"""adds item to user's cart when post functions is called"""
    serializer_class = serializers.CartSerializer

    def post(self,request):
        a = serializers.CartSerializer(data=request.data)
        if a.is_valid():
            a.save()
            return Response({'message': 'j'})
        else:
            return Response(
            a.errors, status=status.HTTP_400_BAD_REQUEST)

class CartItems(APIView):
    serializer_class = serializers.CartOnlySerializer

    def get(self,request):
    """returns the list of products in user's cart"""
        z = int(request.GET.get('q', ''))
        queryset = (models.Cart.objects.filter(UserId=z).values())

        k = []
        for i in queryset:
            p = i.get("ProductId")
            print(p)
            k.append(models.ProductsDescription.objects.filter(connection__id=p))
        print(k)
        abc = serializers.CartOnlySerializer(k, many=True)

        return JsonResponse({'pcartlist': (abc.data)})
```

**serializer.py**

```
class CartSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
"""serialiazer for handling the post request for the cart"""   

    class Meta:
        model = models.Cart
        fields = ('id', 'UserId', 'ProductId','Quantity',)

    def create(self, validated_data):
        user_cart = models.Cart(
            UserId=validated_data.get('UserId'),
            ProductId=validated_data.get('ProductId'),
            Quantity = validated_data.get('Quantity'),
            key=models.ProductsDescription(validated_data.get('ProductId')))       

        user_cart.save()
        return user_cart

class CartListSerializer(serializers.ModelSeriaizer):
    class Meta :
        model = models.ProductsDescription
        fields =('id','category','name','price','description','specification','photos')

class CartListSerializer1(serializers.ListSerializer):
    child = CartListSerializer(allow_null =True, many = True)        


class CartOnlySerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
   connection = CartListSerializer1()

    class Meta:
        model = models.Cart
        fields = ('connection',)
```

There is one model `ProductDescription` which stores all the info about the products and there is model `Cart` which is used to save the ProductId ,UserId and Quantity of the the item user selected.

So,When there is a get request by the user for their cart I want to send the information of the products and the quantity associated with it.
I tried using reverse relation in serializer [and tried to make queries according to reverse relation as said in the documentation.](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/db/queries/#lookups-that-span-relationships)

But i was getting errors of all kind every time I tried.
i have no understanding how can we use foreign keys to make sql joins and the  retrieve info using serializers in django rest framework.

Answer (score 0):

Your code have broken many PEP-8 style guide notes, that i suggest you read or reread, it will help you, maybe not now, but in future.

I strongly suggest you to rething all the app architecture and business logic and use `rest_framework.generics` views, they will do all work for you.

I will put that pieces that i would like to be your start point of writing better app:

**app/models.py**

```
from django.db import models


class Product(models.Model):
    ...

class CartItem(models.Model):
    user = models.ForeignKey(to=settings.AUTH_USER_MODEL)
    product = models.ForeignKey(to='Product')
    quantity = models.PositiveIntegerField(default=0)
```

**app/serializers.py**

```
from . import CartItem, Product


class ProductSerializer(serialziers.ModelsSerializer):
    class Meta:
        model = Product
        fields = (<your_fields>,)


class CartItemSerializer(serialziers.ModelSerializer):
    product = ProductSerializer()

    class Meta:
        model = CartItem
        fields = ('product', 'quantity', )
```

**app/views.py**

```
from rest_framework import generics

from .serializers import CartItemSerializer


class CartAPIView(generics.ListAPIView):
    serializer_class = CartItemSerializer

    def get_queryset(self)
        return CartItem.objects.filter(user=self.request.user)
```

Comment: when using a post function how can we save the values in foreign key attributes? i dont know how to do that that's why i used multiple attributes.

Comment: @Ashishmanchanda there `generics.CreateAPIView` comes in hand, you should see drf tutorial to better understand the way to use them.